# laravel create omits/skips fields

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to seed a couple of databases with laravel seeder, but it seems that it skips some fields..

I'm doing it this way:

```
Item::create(array(
    'name' => 'Category 2',
    'photo' => 'Description of category 2',
    'order' => 1
    'price' => 2.30
    'category_id' => 1,
));
```

The fields 'category_id' and order are not setup in the database..

I'm calling the seeder this way

```
Artisan::call('db:seed',array('--database' => 'tenant_'.$user, '--class' => 'TenantSeeder'));
```

Any idea why does it happen?

If I use the standard

```
$item = new Item;
$item->allfields = "its_value";
$item->save();
```

It works perfectly

UPDATE
Here comes the model:

```
<?php
class Item extends Model {

    //============================================================================
    // PARENT VARIABLES
    //============================================================================
    protected $table = "items";

    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['name','price','description','photo'];   //Items that can be mass assigned
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    protected static $rules = [
        'name'          => 'required|min:3',
        'price'         => '',
        'description'   => '',
    ];

    //============================================================================
    // METHODS
    //============================================================================
    public function getId()         {   return $this->getKey();  }
    public function getName()       {   return $this->name;      }
    public function getPhotoSrc()   {   return $this->photo;     }

    public function item_category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Items_category');
    }

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('active', '=', true);
    }
}
```

And the Scheme

```
Schema::create('items', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            // auto increment id (primary key)
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('name')->default('New Item');
            $table->float('price')->default(0);
            $table->string('photo')->nullable();
            $table->integer('order')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('active')->default(true);
            $table->string('description')->nullable();

            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('items_categories')->onDelete('cascade');

            // created_at, updated_at DATETIME
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes(); //It is not really deleted, just marked as deleted
        });
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you post your schema too?

Comment: Can you post the model definition? maybe you have set a `$guarded` array with those 2 fields in it.

Comment: just updated the quesiton with the requested code

Comment: You don't have `category_id` and `order` within `$fillable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As User2094178 said, 
I didn't have the fields in the $fillable